# C ++ associated container custom type is initialized in the class

Tags: c++, c++11

Two initialization codes for association container objects of custom type comparison
first , not in class:

```
class A
{
public:
   int a;
};
bool compare(const A &a1 , const A &a2)
{ return a1.a > a2.a; }
multiset<A , decltype(compare)> ml(compare);
```

this code is safety
but  () initialization statement cannot be used in the class

```
class z
{
public:
    bool compare(const A &a1 , const A &a2)
    { return a1.a > a2.a; }
    std::multiset<A , decltype(compare)> ml(compare);
};
```

this code use () to initialize the container object will wrong, only can use {}

```
std::multiset<A , decltype(compare)> ml{compare};
```

this code is safety , why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not particular to your compare. While C++11 allows to initialize class members within the definition, you do that either with `{}` (*brace initializer*) or with assignment (*equals initializer*).

```
struct A {
    int a = 42; // works
    int a{42}; // works
    int a(42); // unsupported syntax
};
```

In your example, this would work:

```
std::multiset<A, decltype(compare)> ml = std::multiset<A, decltype(compare)>(compare);
```